# Use COUNT(), ORDER BY and WHERE user = ? simultaneously

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with highscores. When I read them I order them by score DESC.

```
scores
id  name  score
```

i.e.

```
SELECT name, score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC
```

Now I would like to know the rank of a person. I am trying to find a way to combine this without having to loop through all the highscores. This is what I thought of, but I know this will not work. Any ideas?

```
SELECT COUNT(id), name, score FROM scores WHERE name = ? ORDER BY score DESC
```

Should I use WHERE?

Comment: When you say rank, do you mean their index in the resultset?

Comment: What do you mean the rank of a person?

Comment: I mean the counted number. For example: I order them by score DESC. Then I start counting the rows to get their rank: 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: Sounds like you want something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql

Comment: I need to know the row number of 1 record (e.g. WHERE name = ?)

Comment: I found the exact answer to my question here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count everyone with a higher score in a subquery:

```
select coalesce((select count(1) from scores b where b.score > a.score),0) + 1 Rank
, Name
, Score
from Scores a
where name = 'Sarah'
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff0133/3

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by score desc) rank , score from scores order by score desc LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2

Comment: Apologies; I'd answered for `MS SQL`; for `MySQL` please see link in updated answer.

Comment: This is not the answer to my question. I need to know the rank of one person (e.g. WHERE name = ?)

Comment: Apologies; not with it today; corrected again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solution is better than the one I used previously!